# Page tabs loads too slow - umbraco 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, umbraco

I created some pages on umbraco and it works correctly. But i added some datagrids to main page and now, main page's tabs is loading too slow because umbraco is trying to load all data of page on tabs on first call.

So my question is can i load only selected tab on pages? Like lazy load? For example; If i click to first tab, load that data. After click second tab, load data of second tab. Because the standard load of data system is too slow.

Thanks!

ps: Im too newbie on umbraco. So i didnt create custom tabs...etc. Just i created from umbraco dashboard template settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to lazy-load tabs on an Umbraco node. At least that's not provided as functionality.

We've often had a similar problem of a node/page having too much on it (a lot of rich text editors, with each of them loading TinyMCE), and the way around it for us was to pull this content out into child nodes.

By this, I mean that the main page content stays in the page node, but then you could create new document types that are created as children of the content node. You could then use XSLT/Razor to pull in the content stored in these child nodes to be published onto the main content page. By doing this, you'd still have all the content on the page, but it would be split up into multiple nodes, with each of them loading nice and quickly.

Comment: Finally perfect answer! Thanks Ed!